# Download file with actual name by wget

Tags: filenames, wget

I am trying to download a file through HTTP from a web site using `wget`.

When I use:

```
wget http://abc/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file
```

I get only a file called `index.html?acc=GSE48191`.

When I use:

```
wget http://abc/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file -o asd.rpm
```

I get `asd.rpm`, but I want to download with actual name, and don't want to have manually change the name of the downloaded file.

Comment: You might want to ask this sort of question on [bioinformatics.se] next time. It's on topic here as well, and welcome to stay, but you might get more help from people who work in the field.

Comment: @terdon How is asking about wget and \*nix shell behavior on topic on [bioinformatics.se]?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling extracting information from NCBI would be, that's why I suggested it. An answer there would likely involve a simpler, more direct approach to get at the information the OP is looking for rather than a shell solution. Something like "you can get this information more easily from here" for instance.

Comment: Look at the `--trust-server-names` argument to `wget` -

Comment: It's important to note that there is no such thing as "the actual name" of a resource referenced by a URL. A web server responds to a request with some content, and possibly some headers which describe that content in some way, but there doesn't have to be a file involved at all.

Answer (score 34):

```
wget --content-disposition 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file'
```

The file you are downloading is a `tar` archive (a binary file), provided by a dynamic link from a web server. `wget` would normally save the file using part of the URL that you're using, but in this case that's just a REST API endpoint (or something similar) so the name would be unfriendly to work with (it would still be a valid name and the file contents would be the same).

However, in this case the server provides a "Content Disposition" header containing the actual file name, which `wget` is able to use if you use the `--content-disposition` option.  This option is marked "experimental" in my manual for `wget`.

You also need to quote the URL so that the shell does not interpret the `&` and `?` characters in it.

---

The equivalent thing using `curl`:

```
curl -J -O 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file'
```

Or, using the equivalent long options:

```
 curl --remote-header-name --remote-name 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file'
```

---

Once you have downloaded the file, you need to unpack it:

```
tar -xvf GSE48191_RAW.tar
```

Due to the way that this particular archive was created, this will unpack the archive's files into the *current* directory (so creating a new directory, moving the archive there and unpacking it there may be a good idea).  The files in this archive are `gzip`-compressed `CEL` files.

Answer (score 8):

The shell does the usual interpretation of characters, especially `?` as wildcard (which doesn't matter here) and `&` as "put into background". You should have noticed the latter, because the shell response is different from a direct command.

So you need to quote:

```
wget 'http://abc/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file'
```