# wget: how to download a served file keeping its name

Tags: wget

A little IoT server returns a file, whose name is given by current date and time, to make it unique. The format is `2018.07.04.18.22.45.dat`.

Asking for address `XX.XX.XX.XX:5001/read` in a browser (with browser cache disabled) the file is returned with its original name.

Using wget, alas, I cannot preserve the file name:
`wget XX.XX.XX.XX:5001/read` returns the proper content but with name `read`, `read.1`, `read.2`, etc.

Is there the possibility to collect it keeping the name, using `wget` or other commands?

**ADDENDUM**: using `curl XX.XX.XX.XX:5001/read` I obtain the raw content instead of the file.

**ADDENDUM**: as a imperfect workaround, I can generate a filename based on timestamp with `wget -o $(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S.%N.dat")  XX.XX.XX.XX:5001/read`. Of course it doesn't match the original filename.

Comment: Have you tried the `--trust-server-names` option?

Comment: Yes, @ivanivan, I tried it but got `read.X` anyway...

Comment: Have you tried the `--content-disposition` option?

Comment: @Nick ODell, thank you! It works. 
Please move your comment to an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: I also just found by chance the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394464/download-file-with-actual-name-by-wget. I completely missed it before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file with actual name by wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394464/download-file-with-actual-name-by-wget)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `wget --content-disposition <url>`

Explanation: The [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header can be used by a server to suggest a filename for a downloaded file. By default, wget uses the last part of the URL as the filename, but you can override this with `--content-disposition`, which uses the server's suggested name.

More information can be found in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content_002dDisposition).

Comment: You'll want to use `--trust-server-names` as well if you expect a redirect

Comment: `curl -JLO ...` seems to handle more efficently the name from the server.  It avoids the double repeated name problem (XYZ.shXYZ.sh)

Comment: Big J Lo fan, eh? BTW `curl -JLO` and `wget --content-disposition` both do not work perfectly. cURL will use the non-utf-8 file name, and wget will concat the non-utf-8 filename with the utf-8 one, and it won't decode the utf-8 one, either.